# Customize django behavior on requests from mobile app and any sort of web browser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Good day,

So I have made a mobile Android/IOS app that communicates with django backend through the http requests. As you understand the backend is hosted on some https://www.example.com domain...
However, in case a user accesses that domain or any extensions (/home, /profile and etc..) from any web browser from any platform, I want to display just a plain page (maybe the name of the app). How can I do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to add new middleware you can add this in your base.html template. Other way would be to write separate middleware in which you check user_agent and redirect to specific page containing your app name

```
{% if request.user_agent.is_mobile %}
    NAME OF YOUR APP
{% else %}
    Normal page
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I wonder whether user_agent.is_mobile excludes web browsers on mobile

Comment: Also I do not render any template for mobile app, I use DRF to just send serialized data

Comment: But could you render one view for web users in your project? If yes, then you could create middleware which would redirect such users to that specific view

Comment: Actually that middleware is something I think of right now. But I have a worry that user_agent.is_mobile could be both an app user and a user from mobile browser

Comment: If you are doing all requests yourself from an app, then why not add header IS_APP_REQUEST=True into requests? Then you could check if request has such header in middleware, if not redirect to specific view

Comment: Mhh interesting actually I like that, I am not sure if it is the best practice approach but I guess it will work.